# Using csvwrite in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to save floating point values to a file with extension .fd but i'm getting error all the time of this type

Error using dlmwrite (line 130)
Could not open file  name.fd

Error in csvwrite (line 43)
dlmwrite(filename, m, ',', r, c);

the structure of my input is

Columns 1 through 12

```
1.0000    0.1347    0.1360    0.0766    0.0135    0.0051
```

Columns 13 through 24

```
0.0118    0.0085    0.0086    0.0048    0.0045    0.0038
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try to create the file manually in your current working (`pwd`) directory, is this possible?

Comment: I try that but still gives me the same errors

Comment: Please show a completely reproducible exmple. Also make sure you have checked the examples in `doc csvwrite`. Perhaps the problem is a dot in the filename?

Comment: Do you already have 'name.fd' open in Excel? Excel locks a file for exclusive write access when it opens it, so any attempt to open it for write access will fail

Answer (score 0):

This one should work.

```
x=[0.1 2.2 4.1];
csvwrite('dc.fd',x);
```

if you want to store x values at different instances, for ex from a for loop, then you can use

```
dlmwrite('dc.fd',x,'-append')
```